# Print a set width and height using PrintJS

Tags: css, printing, receipt, printjs

I'm trying to print a receipt using PrintJS, however, I can't seem to be able to print a receipt that ends after the data end, instead, it acts as A4 paper.

```
      printJS({
        printable: "printable",
        type: "html",
        targetStyles: "*",
        style: `@page { margin: 0mm; size: 80m 80m; } @media print { body { margin: 0mm; width: 80mm; height: 80mm } }`,
      });
```

This is what the element looks like.

[image]

This is what the paper is printed like(which is essentially an A4 paper).

[image]

This is the height of the paper regardless of size/height I set by the way, the width adapts okay but the height just simply refuses to change.

Answer (score 0):

[image: new paper]

you need add new paper, in Control Panel.